# How to change the container height to 80% of the body height, and maintain aspect ratio?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsiveness

I have an issue right now that i haven't been able to solve

Even some answers in SO promote the use of `vh` unit but due to backwards compatibility for the APP i don't want to use that.

This is what i have in my layout css

```
html {;
  height: 100%;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
}

 html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

 body{
  position: relative;
}
```

I'm using AngularJS with bootstrap + sass + jade

so my layout look like this mockup:

[image]

A fixed body background with a semi-transparent container in the middle. 
On the bottom of the container i have 2 navigation buttons, that switch views using ui-router

But basically I want to be able to set a fixed height for the container relative to the height of the viewport and keep it on different resolutions till mobile devices.

Comment: In the title you state that you want to maintain the ratio, but then in the question there is no reference to that ...

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
div.container {
    box-sizing: border-box; //if this isn't already inherited for some reason
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
}
```